# Getting THREE.EventDispatcher is undefined when instantiating a THREE.OrbitControls class with THREE.js, THREE.OrbitControls and typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js, webpack

I'm trying to learn typescript with three.js and can't figure out why I'm getting this error. In the init function I'm creating a new THREE.OrbitControls controller. Using https://github.com/pinqy520/three-typescript-starter as setup.

Error recieved: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined**

```
    // three.
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import * as ColladaLoader from 'three-collada-loader';
    import * as OrbitControls from 'three-orbit-controls';

// Set the scene size
const WIDTH: number = window.innerWidth;
const HEIGHT: number = window.innerHeight;

// Set camera attributes
const VIEW_ANGLE: number = 45;
const ASPECT: number = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
const NEAR: number = 0.1;
const FAR: number = 10000;



// Create a WebGL renderer, camera
// and a scene
const renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
const scene: THREE.Scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Load a model into the scene
let monster: any;
const loader: ColladaLoader = new ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
loader.load(
    '/src/monster.dae',
    (collada: THREE.ColladaModel): void => {
        monster = collada.scene;
        monster.scale.set(0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
        monster.position.set(0, 0.1, 0);

        scene.add(monster);

        init();
        animate()
    });

const init = (): void => {
    // Get the DOM element to attach to
    const container = document.querySelector('#canvas');

    // Set the position of the camera
    // and add it to the scene
    camera.position.set(0, 2, 10)
    scene.add(camera);

    //
    const gridHelper: THREE.GridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 20);
    scene.add(gridHelper);

    //
    const ambientLight: THREE.AmbientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xcccccc)
    scene.add(ambientLight);

    const directionalLight: THREE.DirectionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight((0xffffff));
    directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, -1).normalize;
    scene.add(directionalLight);

    // Start the renderer
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // Attach the renderer-supplied
    // DOM element.
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // Create a controll class around
    // the camera
    debugger
    let controls: THREE.OrbitControls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
}

// Recursive function
let animate = (): void => {

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    render();

}

// Recursive rendering function
let render = (): void => {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

Comment: is it full error, can you show full error show ?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined.

    at new module.exports (index.js:891)
    at init (main.ts:103)
    at loader.load (main.ts:51)
    at parse (index.js:198)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (index.js:78)

Comment: Having the same issue while trying to update the threejs version from 76 to 86.
The coordination system seems also to have changed from 76 to 77 version, but can't find any mention of it.

Answer (score 1):

According to this
[post on GITHUB](https://github.com/sohamkamani/three-objmtll-loader/issues/1)
that syntax no longer works.  So change OrbitControls like this:

```html
 THREE.EventDispatcher.apply( this );
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a change recent versions of the threejs to the way you use the default exports of a module.

So, instead of using:

```
import THREE from 'three';
```

You should use:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
```

Comment: Doesn't solve it, 'three-orbit-controls' is its own package.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/orbit-controls-es6

One slight difference to make note of:

Do `new OrbitControls` instead of `new THREE.OrbitControls`

```
import OrbitControls from 'orbit-controls-es6';

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```